# Avoid table locked with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm writing a C# program that accesses to a SQLite DB.

At the initial phase I read a custom DB table version and, if older, i delete the table and I regenerate it.

The problem is that when  go to drop the table I receive a lot of errors like:

> SQLite error (6): statement aborts at 21: [DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;] database table is locked

I discovered that probably is because the previous SELECT command is active, then I need like to reset/finalize it - but how?

I tried with `rdr.Close()` and then with `cmd.Reset()` but without positive results.

My code:

```
Debug.WriteLine("[DbManager] check db version..");
cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from settings;", sqlConnection);
try {
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.Read()){
        // Read and check version
        var i = rdr.GetOrdinal("version");
        var version = rdr.GetInt32(i);
        LogManager.Write(
            String.Format(
                "> Version: {0} - CurrentVersion: {1}", version, CURRENT_DB_VERSION
            )
        );
        if (version < CURRENT_DB_VERSION){
            // Cancella la tabella orders
            cmd.Reset();    //
            rdr.Close();

            /*var cmdDrop*/ cmd = new SQLiteCommand("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;", sqlConnection);
            try {
                /*cmdDrop*/cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ...
```

Comment: the SqliteDataReader is disposable. Try disposing "rdr" it and see if that helps.

Comment: SQLiteCommand is Disposable, no rdr... Added cmd.Dispose() but the error is there.